# Reload .Xresources without restarting the xterm

Tags: bash, vim, escaping, xterm, alt-key

To use ALT key in vim without tweaking, the escaping should be disabled in xterm.
Without escaping the ALT will not work in bash for shortcuts.

to work around I need to reload this option before starting vim:

```
XTerm*metaSendsEscape: false | xrdb -load
```

Any idea how I can reload .Xresource and make changes take effect without restarting the terminal window ?
Open to other terminal to have ALT work both in vim and bash.

Comment: try xrdb ~/.Xresource

Comment: This is the same as cat .Xresource | xrdb -load. it requires a terminal restart.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

xterm will **not** reread resources just because you run `xrdb`.  X applications only read resources when they are initializing.

Besides the menu entry (added in [patch #122, 1999](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_122)), one could use two other ways to change the `metaSendsEscape` resource:

- escape sequence, documented in [*XTerm Control Sequences*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-?-Pm-h:Ps-=-1-0-3-6.1F81)

  `CSI ? Pm h
            DEC Private Mode Set (DECSET).
   ...
              Ps = 1 0 3 6  -> Send ESC   when Meta modifies a key.  (This
            enables the metaSendsEscape resource).`
- [editres](http://www.rahul.net/kenton/editres.html) (but very cumbersome due to the large number of resources)

Answer (score 98):

This will reload the `.Xresources`:

```
xrdb ~/.Xresources
```

Source: [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources)

Comment: This answer should be deleted, since it is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @ThomasDickey This question is 1st result for googling "reload Xresources".

Comment: @Daerdemandt It's also 1st result for googling "reload xresources without restarting xterm". What's your point?

Comment: This answer has been suggested and rejected in the commments to the question. It does not work *without* restarting any program.

Comment: This plus making a new terminal window worked for me.

Comment: +1 to delete this answer. In the question I pipe to xrdb -load which is equivalent this this. I obviously tried this.

Comment: i will immolate and delete it

Answer (score 4):

YAY, just checked, and XTerm has the option in its menu! I *thought* I saw it in there...

XTerm responds to each of left-, middle- (aka scrollwheel) and right-click with individual option menus when you're holding down the Ctrl key.

In your case, "Meta Sends Escape" is in the ctrl+left-click menu :)

Also, examining all three menus (if just to be aware of the options' existence) is a very good idea. I frequently use the font selector, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Had to put `xterm*metaSendsEscape: true` into `.Xdefaults`, using `.Xresources` did not want to work for me under 16.04.

Followed up by a `xrdb ~/.Xdefaults`.